# webview not loading correctly in application

Tags: android, webview

I have an application that has a tab widget in it.  One of the tabs loads a webview for me and it is not loading correctly.  when i load the same address in just my phone browser it loads fine.  here is the code for the webview i'm using

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Sermons extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

 // Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
    // if there is an error loading this page (see below).
    webview.loadUrl("http://canyonculberts.com/ucc/?page_id=93");
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.setInitialScale(1);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);

}
}
```

anyone have any thoughts on what i can do different on this to make it work correctly?  Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need android.permission.INTERNET permission.

Second, you may need setJavaScriptEnabled(true) to settings, and do loadUrl at the very last.

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://canyonculberts.com/ucc/?page_id=93");
```

Comment: ok i have internet permission done already, where do i do the setJavaScriptEnable at is it in the code i have here or where?

Comment: WOW that worked great and worked perfectly THANK YOU FOR THAT VERY MUCH

Answer (score 1):

You have to try this code It wiil help you!

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);

         WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();

         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

         webview.loadUrl("url");
```

Comment: gives me an error on the (R.id.web) any suggestions.  it says web cannot be resolved

Comment: @Bryan see edited answer first. I think its solve there was variable problem

Comment: I think we are on the right path but now my app is force closing on launch and this is all i've changed, any ideas why

Comment: its giving a fatal error on the main activity that loads the tabhost now, not sure how its related to this though

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..

```
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: get unresolved error with the (R.id.webview) with this code as well

Comment: R u added the webview widget in ur xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, After I tried many times .. I Solved it by adding this line.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```